# Why is there so much dragonglass in Dragonstone?

Tags: game-of-thrones

We know there is a lot of dragonglass in Dragonstone. Why there in particular?

Comment: It might become simpler if you reverse the question : "why would a place with a lot of dragonglass be called Dragonstone"?

Comment: Lol, "We named our neighborhood Dragonstone because it sounded cool and next thing you know..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer uses quotes from the books but it is the same answer in the show, the books just give some better, more detailed information.

> "Dragonglass," Osha named it as she sat down beside Luwin, bandagings in hand.
>
> "Obsidian," Maester Luwin insisted, holding out his wounded arm. "**Forged in the fires of the gods, far below the earth.** The children of the forest hunted with that, thousands of years ago. The children worked no metal. In place of mail, they wore long shirts of woven leaves and bound their legs in bark, so they seemed to melt into the wood. In place of swords, they carried blades of obsidian."

As you can see dragonglass is volcanic in nature and so it stands to reason that Dragonstone is probably built on a volcanic island.